# Creating loop for 3d matrix

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have two 3D matrices as below.

```
Original_data = cat(3, O_range, O_Doppler, O_Angle);
Measured_data = cat(3, M_range, M_Doppler, M_angle);
```

Below is a m.file for the nearest distance calculation between O_range and M_range. How do I calculate nearest distance between O_Doppler & M_doppler and O_angle & M_angle from 3D matrix to the loop.

```
function [ res ] = nearest_Distance( O_range, M_Range, Number_of_object)
res=nan(size(O_range,1),Number_of_object);
  for ix = 1:Number_of_object
    dist = abs(bsxfun(@minus,M_Range,O_range(:,ix)));
    [~,col] = min(dist,[],2);
    res(:,ix) = diag(M_range(:,col));
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng for editing

Comment: What do you mean with _to the loop_?